# How do I integrate Expression<Func<>> to clean up my Linq-to-Entity queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to use the `Expression<Func<>>` method to clean up my DTO Linq-to-Query Selects so as not to make them grow anymore than what they already have. I'm still a little confused as to how to integrate them into my own project.

An example:

```
public IQueryable<ExampleDTO> SelectDTO()
{
  var repository = new ExampleUDCRepository();

  return db.Example
           .Select(v => new ExampleDTO
           {
             ExampleID     = v.ExampleID,
             MasterGroupID = v.MasterGroupID,
             //...etc

             ExampleUDCs = db.ExampleUDCs
                             .Where(vudc => vudc.ExampleID == v.ExampleID)
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(vudc => new ExampleDCDTO
                             {
                               ExampleID    = vudc.ExampleID,
                               UDCHeadingID = vudc.UDCHeadingID,
                               UDCValue     = vudc.UDCValue
                             })
           });
```

Some of my other DTO setup and return methods are even bigger and sloppier.

What I really want to do is something like this:

```
public IQueryable<ExampleDTO> SelectDTO()
{
  var repository = new ExampleUDCRepository();

  return db.Example
           .Select(v => new ExampleDTO
           {
             ExampleID     = v.ExampleID,
             MasterGroupID = v.MasterGroupID,
             //...etc

             ExampleUDCs = new ExampleUDCsRepository().SelectDTO(v);
             // SelectDTO(Example v) in that repository would call
             // any other SelectDTO it might need and so forth
           });
```

Problem is, Linq doesn't know how to convert methods like that into an SQL statement, which is where the `Expression<Func<>>` method has come into play for passing around this sort of thing.

My understanding of `Expression<Func<>>` is limited and I haven't found any documentation out there yet that makes what I'm trying to do much clearer.

What is the best way of integrating `Expression<Func<>>` into my DTO like this?

Comment: This is an interesting and well-described question, but please take some extra care when pasting the code. IDE's tabs converted to 4*space are not always really readable at first 'paste'. I've trimmed it a little bit, no real changes, and it does not hurt the eyes as much as earlier. But, of course, as all cosmetic things, it's just my personal opinion and small suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off we'll need a few helper methods.  We'll start off with this simple class to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Next we'll create an extension method to use it:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Finally, we'll create a `Combine` method that will combine two expressions together.  It will take one expression that computes an intermediate result from a value, and then another that uses both the first value and the intermediate result to determine the final result.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Combine<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], param)
        .Replace(second.Parameters[1], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

Next we can define the method that computes the ExampleDCDTO objects given an example object.  It will be a straight extraction of what you had above, with the exception that instead of returning an `IEnumerable<ExampleDCDTO>` it'll need to return an expression that turns an `Example` into such a sequence:

```
public Expression<Func<Example, IEnumerable<ExampleDCDTO>>> SelectDTO()
{
    return v => db.ExampleUDCs.Where(vudc => vudc.ExampleID == v.ExampleID)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(vudc => new ExampleDCDTO
        {
            ExampleID = vudc.ExampleID,
            UDCHeadingID = vudc.UDCHeadingID,
            UDCValue = vudc.UDCValue
        });
}
```

Now to bring it all together we can call this `SelectDTO` method to generate the expression that computes the intermediate value and `Combine` it with another expression that uses it:

```
public IQueryable<ExampleDTO> SelectDTO()
{
    ExampleUDCRepository repository = new ExampleUDCRepository();
    return db.Example
            .Select(repository.SelectDTO().Combine((v, exampleUDCs) =>
                new ExampleDTO()
                {
                    ExampleID = v.ExampleID,
                    MasterGroupID = v.MasterGroupID,
                    ExampleUDCs = exampleUDCs,
                }));
}
```

Another option, for those using [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), is to use `AsExpandable` instead of all of my helper methods.  Using this approach would still require creating the `SelectDTO` method that return an `Expression<Func<Example, IEnumerable<ExampleDCDTO>>>`, but you would instead combine the result like so:

```
public IQueryable<ExampleDTO> SelectDTO()
{
    ExampleUDCRepository repository = new ExampleUDCRepository();
    var generateUDCExpression = repository.SelectDTO();
    return db.Example
        .AsExpandable()
        .Select(v =>
            new ExampleDTO()
            {
                ExampleID = v.ExampleID,
                MasterGroupID = v.MasterGroupID,
                ExampleUDCs = generateUDCExpression.Invoke(v),
            });
}
```

Comment: My only other question is the .Invoke() method there. Does my SelectDTO, the one being called inside the first one, need to change at all? such as `Expression<Func<Example, IEnumerable<ExampleDCDTO>>> SelectDTO(Example v)` ?

Comment: I can't get that implementation to work the way you have it. Says Invoke() has invalid arguments. Thanks

Comment: @nzondlo Then don't use the LINQKit solution, use the other solution.