# Mapping DTO classes with Expression<Func> inside another Expression<Func>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dto

I'm working with the Entity Framework Code First and trying to map from my entity classes to my DTO classes. But I'm having difficult figuring out how to write the Selector.

In this small example, I have created a Person class and a Address class.

In the DTO classes I have created a Selector, which maps from my Entity to my DTO, but is it not possible to use AddressDto.Selector inside the PersonDto.Selector?

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to map this to a DTO classes.

```
    public class PersonDto
        {
            public static Expression<Func<Person, PersonDto>> Selector = 
            entity => new PersonDto
                {
                     Id = entity.Id,
                     Name = entity.Name,
                     Address = ??? AddressDTO.Selector
                };

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public AddressDto Address { get; set; }
        }

        public class AddressDto
        {
            public static Expression<Func<Address, AddressDto>> Selector = 
            entity => new AddressDto
                 {
                     Id = entity.Id,
                     Street = entity.Street
                 };

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Street { get; set; }
        }
```

I know that I could just write this inside PersonDto.Selector

```
Address = new AddressDto
                     {
                         Id = entity.Address.Id,
                         Street = entity.Address.Street
                     };
```

But I'm looking for a way to reuse the Selector from the AddressDto class. To keep the code clean and separate responsibility between classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, we're going to need several helper methods here, but once we have them, things should be fairly simple.

We'll start out with this class that can replace all instance of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Then an extension method to make calling it easier:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Next we'll write a compose extension method. This will take a lambda that computes an intermediate result, and then another lambda that computes a final result based on the intermediate result and returns a new lambda that takes what the initial lambda returns and returns the output of the final lambda.  In effect it calls one function, and then calls another on the result of the first, but with expressions, not methods.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

Now we'll create a `Combine` method.  This will be similar, but subtly different.  It will take a lambda that computes an intermediate result, and a function that uses both the initial input, and the intermediate input, to compute a final result.  It's basically the same as the `Compose` method, but the second function also gets to know about the first parameter:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Combine<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], param)
        .Replace(second.Parameters[1], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

Okay, now that we have all of this, we get to use it.  First thing we'll do is create a static constructor; we won't be able to inline all we have to do into the field initializer. (The other option is to make a static method that computes this, and have the initializer call it.)

After that we'll create an expression that take a person and returns it's address.  It's one of the missing puzzle pieces in the expressions that you have.  Using that, we'll compose that address selector with the `AddressDto` selector, and then use `Combine` on that.  Using that we have a lambda that takes a `Person` and an `AddressDTO` and returns a `PersonDTO`.  So in there we have basically what you wanted to have, but with an `address` parameter given to us to assign to the address:

```
static PersonDto()
{
    Expression<Func<Person, Address>> addressSelector =
        person => person.Address;

    Selector = addressSelector.Compose(AddressDto.Selector)
            .Combine((entity, address) => new PersonDto
            {
                Id = entity.Id,
                Name = entity.Name,
                Address = address,
            });
}
```

Comment: Microsoft's official docs (albeit written by one guy) list the Expression<Func<>> method for casting your results as a DTO here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing. I don't understand why there isn't already a Microsoft way of making a complex DTO that way built-in, and we have to make these extra methods (re: hack) to do that. Surely this can't be a unique user-case.

Comment: @nzondlo Well, any sort of "automatic" solution would probably have to be a hack.  It'd need to make guesses and judgement calls as to what it thinks is going on.  By doing it manually you can be sure it *is* correct, so it's less hacky.  It's also not really that hard at all once you've built up a handful of base tools for manipulating expressions.  (Some of those I *do* wish could be in the base class library; I almost never answer an `Expression` related question without appending in my own definition of `Replace`.)  These helper methods were intentionally written to be reusable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253205/how-do-i-integrate-expressionfunc-to-clean-up-my-linq-to-entity-queries Maybe I'm thinking more in reference to the Answer you gave to my question that was pretty similar. I don't see how that functionality can't be built into the Linq-To-Entity method-based API

Answer (score -4):

First off, I would use only a single class to do this. No need for DTO class that does the same thing.

If you insist on having secondary DTO classes, then I would simply create extension methods for them. Ex: PersonDTO personDto = myPerson.ToDTO()