# How to make a Lambda expression Reusable in multiple LINQ Queries

Tags: c#, linq, function, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var result = from person in dbContext.Person
             select new
             {
                 FirstName = person.FirstName,
                 LastName = person.LastName,

                 // I want to save this logic
                 JobCount = person.Jobs.Count(x => x.Completed)
             };
}
```

To avoid repeating myself in other LINQ queries, I would like to make the `JobCount` lambda logic available for use in other queries.

I thought I might be able to use `Func<Person, int>`, like so:

```
public Func<Person, int> GetCompletedJobsForPerson = person => person.Jobs.Count(x => x.Completed);

var result = from person in dbContext.Person
             select new
             {
                 FirstName = person.FirstName,
                 LastName = person.LastName,

                 // Use Invoke to get amount
                 JobCount = GetCompletedJobsForPerson.Invoke(person)
             };
}
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:** This fails because the method cannot be mapped to an SQL statement and causes a `NotSupportedException`

> NotSupportedException was unhandled
>   The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

How can I make the lambda reusable from multiple LINQ queries?

Comment: Did you try it? And why use the `Invoke()` method explicitly for a delegate, when you can just `GetCompletedJobsForPerson(person)`?

Comment: oooo... I didn't realize that I could just use the method name for Func<T,T>, I will give that a go!

Comment: @PeterDuniho Using the method invocation operator will have identical semantics, and neither will work, for the same reason.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, I think you need to review the reason.. It does contain a problem statement, the problem is that I'd like the lambda to be reusable.

Comment: @Servy: yes, I'm aware they are the same. I'm just pointing out that idiomatically the `Invoke()` method is pretty much never used. As for whether it would actually work or not, absent a complete code example you can't say for sure. The `dbContext` hints that the OP may be using LINQ-to-SQL, and yes in that case the delegate can't be shipped over to the database server. But if this is LINQ-to-objects, or if the OP can use `AsEnumerable()` to make these particular queries that way, it should work fine. He would know one way or the other _if he'd just try it_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The odds of `dbContext` being a database context, and thus an `IQueryable` rather than an object returning `IEnumerable` objects, is *astronomically* high.  But yes, if he's being intentionally misleading and in fact only has a LINQ to objects query, then it'll be fine.  If not, it'll fail.  I certainly don't dispute that he should actually try it and watch it fail before asking his question, but I have no doubts that it actually will.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can't _just try it_ because I'm in the middle of a large amount of re-factoring.  Thanks for the suggestion though...

Comment: @Coulton If you can't try it (which is extremely odd, you most certainly should be able to; if you can't, that's indicative of a larger problem you should resolve) then you should wait to ask the question until you're in a position where you *can*.

Comment: It's not strange, it's just that I'm refactoring my whole code base.

Comment: Then create a new console app, throw in your data model, and write some simple tests that execute just this one query and nothing else.  That the application that this query will eventually be used in isn't stable shouldn't prevent you from being able to test this query.  If it does, again, then you're not ready to ask the question here and should wait until you are ready to ask it.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Not in an easy and intuitive way.

Comment: @xanatos It's most certainly possible.  Not using the exact syntax shown, but using a morale equivalent.

Comment: @Servy I've written my thought in an answer.

Comment: @xanatos You're clearly in the ballpark of what would need to be done.  Of course, the vast majority of the work that it would take to write such a solution can be done in a reusable way, so that you write it once and then can use it any number of times, rather than writing the expression manipulation code from scratch every single time.

Comment: @Servy Sadly this isn't the Expression tree evening for me :-)

Comment: As Servy says, it is always possible to create [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the question you are asking. Indeed, this is _expected_ from questioners and the lack of such an example will often get a question closed.

Comment: That said, it would be helpful if you could clarify whether the queries where you want to use this reusable method or delegate need to be executed as SQL queries. If not, the _simplest_ approach is to just add `AsEnumerable()`. I.e. `from person in dbContext.Person.AsEnumerable()`. Then you can use method call or delegate as desired. Whether this harms performance in an important way depends on how the query is used later, context you haven't provided here. But if you're just going to materialize the entire query in-memory at some point anyway, it probably won't make things worse.

Comment: @Coulton See the big example of code. Now it works...

Comment: @Servy In the end it was the number of lines I had thought... 200-400 lines. You seemed to be interested in it. It is in my response.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have executed the above code and I have verified that it causes a `NotSupportedException` when the above code is executed with a custom Func<> method.  Thanks

Comment: @xanatos It's nowhere near 200-400 lines.  You can do it in just a few dozen.

Comment: @Servy Yes, the super-compact is probably 100 lines... But I added expandable properties, a little checking, an attribute and something else and the number of lines balooned :-)

Comment: @xanatos My robust version is 31 lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20253825/1159478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done in an easy way (and if it could be done easily, someone would have done it :-) )

What could be done is use the same trick of [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and create an `AsExpandable` that will replace some "tokens" (function calls) in your query with some other function calls. But I don't think it's worth the trouble. It is some hundred lines of code to do it "correctly".

The other problem is that the query would then need this special method to be called:

```
var result = (from person in dbContext.Person
              select new
              {
                  FirstName = person.FirstName,
                  LastName = person.LastName,

                  // Use Invoke to get amount
                  JobCount = GetCompletedJobsForPerson(person)
              }).FixMethodCalls();
```

Ok... it was difficult, but doable:

```
// v0.11 Codename: Handle with Care+ (+ == Plus)

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ExpandableAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Just to know the suffix to use :-)
    public static readonly string ExpandableSuffix = "Expression";
}

// Replaces method and properties calls to "special" method calls that 
// are Expression(s). These method/property calls can be used anywhere in 
// the query (Select, Where, GroupBy, ...)
// Remember to use .AsExpandable2() somewhere in your query (it must be a 
// "top level" part of the query):

// OK:
// var res1 = (from x in table select x).AsExpandable2();
// var res2 = table.AsExpandable().Where(x => true);
// var res3 = table.Where(x => true).AsExpandable2();
// var res4 = table.Where(x => true).AsExpandable2().Select(x => x);
// var res5 = table.Where(x => true).AsExpandable2().Select(x => x).AsExpandable2();

// Not OK:
// var res1 = table.Select(x => x.subtable.AsExpandable2());

// **Method calls**

// The methods to be expanded can be static or instance. There must be
// a corresponding **static* method with same name and suffix 
// "Expression", that doesn't have parameters and returns an Expression 
// with a certain signature.

// Static:
// var res2 = table.AsExpandable2().Select(x => MyClass.StaticMethod(1, x, 2, 3));
// There must be in the class MyClass
// public/private/protected static Expression<Func<int, MyClass, int, int, returnType(StaticMethod)>> StaticMethodExpression()

// Instance:
// var res1 = table.AsExpandable2().Select(x => x.InstanceMethod(1, 2, 3));
// There must be in the class x.GetType() 
// public/private/protected static Expression<Func<x.GetType(), int, int, int, returnType(InstanceMethod)>> InstanceMethodExpression()

// Note that multiple "tables" can be passed as parameters:
// Static:
// var res3 = (from x in table1 from y in table2 select new { x, y }).AsExpandable2().Select(z => MyClass.StaticMethod(1, z.x, z.y, 2, 3));
// There must be in the class MyClass
// public/private/protected/internal static Expression<Func<int, x.GetType(), y.GetType(), int, int, returnType(StaticMethod)>> StaticMethodExpression()

// Instance:
// var res4 = (from x in table1 from y in table2 select new { x, y }).AsExpandable2().Select(z => z.x.StaticMethod(1, z.y, 2, 3));
// There must be in the class x.GetType() 
// public/private/protected/internal static Expression<Func<x.GetType(), int, y.GetType(), int, int, returnType(StaticMethod)>> InstanceMethodExpression()

// **Properties**

// Same as with method calls, but with properties :-)
// (useful for things like FullName, where 
// FullName = Name + ' ' + Surname)
// Remember that the *Expression property must be **static**!

// Static (not very useful :-) ):
// var res1 = table.AsExpandable2().Select(x => MyClass.StaticProperty);
// There must be in the class MyClass
// public/private/protected/internal static Expression<Func<MyClass.StaticProperty.GetType()>> StaticPropertyExpression { get; }

// Instance:
// var res2 = table.AsExpandable2().Select(x => x.InstanceProperty);
// There must be in the class x.GetType() 
// public/private/protected/internal static Expression<Func<x.GetType(), x.InstanceProperty.GetType())>> InstancePropertyExpression { get; }

public static class MethodsPropertiesExpander
{
    // Because AsExpandable() is already used by http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx
    public static IQueryable<T> AsExpandable2<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        if (source is MethodsPropertiesExpander<T>)
        {
            return source;
        }

        return new MethodsPropertiesExpander<T>(source);
    }
}

public interface IMethodsPropertiesExpander
{
}

public class MethodsPropertiesExpander<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>, IQueryProvider, IMethodsPropertiesExpander
{
    public readonly IQueryable<T> Query;

    public MethodsPropertiesExpander(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        if (!(query is IMethodsPropertiesExpander))
        {
            Expression expression = MethodsPropertiesReplacer.Default.Visit(query.Expression);
            Query = expression == query.Expression ? query : query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
        }
        else
        {
            Query = query;
        }
    }

    /* IQueryable<T> */

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Query.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return Query.ElementType; }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return Query.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    /* IQueryProvider */

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new MethodsPropertiesExpander<TElement>(Query.Provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression));
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        Type iqueryableArgument = GetIQueryableTypeArgument(expression.Type);
        MethodInfo createQueryImplMethod = typeof(MethodsPropertiesExpander<T>)
            .GetMethod("CreateQuery", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .MakeGenericMethod(iqueryableArgument);

        return (IQueryable)createQueryImplMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { expression });
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (!(Query.Provider is IMethodsPropertiesExpander))
        {
            // We want to expand it only once :-)
            expression = MethodsPropertiesReplacer.Default.Visit(expression);
        }

        return Query.Provider.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        if (!(Query.Provider is IMethodsPropertiesExpander))
        {
            // We want to expand it only once :-)
            expression = MethodsPropertiesReplacer.Default.Visit(expression);
        }

        return Query.Provider.Execute(expression);
    }

    /* Implementation methods */

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the T of IQueryablelt;T&gt;
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected static Type GetIQueryableTypeArgument(Type type)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> interfaces = type.IsInterface ?
            new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) :
            type.GetInterfaces();
        Type argument = (from x in interfaces
                         where x.IsGenericType
                         let gt = x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                         where gt == typeof(IQueryable<>)
                         select x.GetGenericArguments()[0]).FirstOrDefault();
        return argument;
    }

    /* Utility classes */

    protected sealed class MethodsPropertiesReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        // Single instance is enough!
        public static readonly MethodsPropertiesReplacer Default = new MethodsPropertiesReplacer();

        private MethodsPropertiesReplacer()
        {
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = node.Member as PropertyInfo;
            MethodInfo getter;

            // We handle only properties (that aren't indexers) that have 
            // a get
            if (property != null && property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && (getter = property.GetGetMethod(true)) != null)
            {
                // We work only on methods marked as [ExpandableAttribute]
                var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExpandableAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    string name = property.Name + ExpandableAttribute.ExpandableSuffix;

                    var property2 = property.DeclaringType.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);

                    if (property2 == null || property2.GetGetMethod(true) == null)
                    {
                        if (property2 == null)
                        {
                            if (property.DeclaringType.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null) != null)
                            {
                                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} isn't static!", property.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                            }

                            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} not found!", property.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                        }

                        // property2.GetGetMethod(true) == null
                        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} doesn't have a getter!", property.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                    }

                    // Instance Parameters have the additional 
                    // "parameter" of the declaring type
                    var argumentsPlusReturnTypes = getter.IsStatic ?
                        new[] { node.Type } :
                        new[] { property.DeclaringType, node.Type };

                    var funcType = typeof(Func<>).Assembly.GetType(string.Format("System.Func`{0}", argumentsPlusReturnTypes.Length));

                    var returnType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(funcType.MakeGenericType(argumentsPlusReturnTypes));

                    if (property2.PropertyType != returnType)
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} has wrong return type!", property.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                    }

                    var expression = (LambdaExpression)property2.GetValue(null, null);

                    // Instance Members have the additional "parameter" 
                    // of the declaring type
                    var arguments2 = getter.IsStatic ? new Expression[0] : new[] { node.Expression };

                    var replacer = new SimpleExpressionReplacer(expression.Parameters, arguments2);
                    var body = replacer.Visit(expression.Body);

                    return this.Visit(body);
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            MethodInfo method = node.Method;

            // We work only on methods marked as [ExpandableAttribute]
            var attribute = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExpandableAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute != null)
            {
                string name = method.Name + ExpandableAttribute.ExpandableSuffix;

                var method2 = method.DeclaringType.GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);

                if (method2 == null)
                {
                    if (method.DeclaringType.GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null) != null)
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} isn't static!", method.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                    }

                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} not found!", method.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                }

                // Instance methods have the additional "parameter" of
                // the declaring type
                var argumentsPlusReturnTypes = method.IsStatic ?
                    node.Arguments.Select(x => x.Type).Concat(new[] { node.Type }).ToArray() :
                    new[] { method.DeclaringType }.Concat(node.Arguments.Select(x => x.Type)).Concat(new[] { node.Type }).ToArray();

                var funcType = typeof(Func<>).Assembly.GetType(string.Format("System.Func`{0}", argumentsPlusReturnTypes.Length));

                var returnType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(funcType.MakeGenericType(argumentsPlusReturnTypes));

                if (method2.ReturnType != returnType)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0}.{1} has wrong return type!", method.DeclaringType.FullName, name));
                }

                var expression = (LambdaExpression)method2.Invoke(null, null);

                // Instance methods have the additional "parameter" of
                // the declaring type
                var arguments2 = method.IsStatic ? node.Arguments : new[] { node.Object }.Concat(node.Arguments);

                var replacer = new SimpleExpressionReplacer(expression.Parameters, arguments2);
                var body = replacer.Visit(expression.Body);

                return this.Visit(body);
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}

// A simple expression visitor to replace some nodes of an expression 
// with some other nodes
public class SimpleExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> Replaces;

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Dictionary<Expression, Expression> replaces)
    {
        Replaces = replaces;
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(IEnumerable<Expression> from, IEnumerable<Expression> to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();

        using (var enu1 = from.GetEnumerator())
        using (var enu2 = to.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                bool res1 = enu1.MoveNext();
                bool res2 = enu2.MoveNext();

                if (!res1 || !res2)
                {
                    if (!res1 && !res2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!res1)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("from shorter");
                    }

                    throw new ArgumentException("to shorter");
                }

                Replaces.Add(enu1.Current, enu2.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { from, to } };
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        Expression to;

        if (node != null && Replaces.TryGetValue(node, out to))
        {
            return base.Visit(to);
        }

        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

I've added a bonus: you can even "expand" special properties. The instructions on how to use it are in the big comment at the beginning. Now I'll give you some examples:

```
// Generated by EF
public partial class MyClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyInnerClass> MyInnerClass;
}

// Written by you (remember the partial!)
public partial class MyClass
{
    [Expandable]
    public int CountMyInnerClass()
    {
        // Not necessary to implement, unless you want to use it C#-side
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Expandable]
    public int CountMyInnerClassPlus(int num)
    {
        // Not necessary to implement, unless you want to use it C#-side
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Expandable]
    public int CountMyInnerClassProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Not necessary to implement, unless you want to use it C#-side
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    [Expandable]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            // Not necessary to implement, unless you want to use it C#-side
            return Name + " " + Surname;
        }
    }

    protected static Expression<Func<MyClass, int>> CountMyInnerClassExpression()
    {
        return x => x.MyInnerClass.Count();
    }

    protected static Expression<Func<MyClass, int, int>> CountMyInnerClassPlusExpression()
    {
        return (x, num) => x.MyInnerClass.Count() + num;
    }

    protected static Expression<Func<MyClass, int>> CountMyInnerClassPropertyExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return x => x.MyInnerClass.Count();
        }
    }

    protected static Expression<Func<MyClass, string>> FullNameExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return x => x.Name + " " + x.Surname;
        }
    }
}
```

and then, in some other class class (perhaps the ones of the query):

```
[Expandable]
public static int LocalCountMyInnerClassPlus(MyClass x, int num)
{
    // Not necessary to implement, unless you want to use it C#-side
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static Expression<Func<MyClass, int, int>> LocalCountMyInnerClassPlusExpression()
{
    return (x, num) => x.MyInnerClass.Count() + num;
}
```

and then

```
var query = (from x in db.MyClasses
             select new
                 {
                     x.ID,
                     x.FullName,
                     Count1 = x.CountMyInnerClass(),
                     Count2 = x.CountMyInnerClassPlus(5),
                     Count3 = x.CountMyInnerClassProperty,
                     Count4 = LocalCountMyInnerClassPlus(x, 10),
                 }).AsExpandable2().ToList();
```

and it just works :-)

Comment: oh my gosh, thank you for taking the time to work on this and work it out!!  Thank you!