# Calling a Method inside LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have something like this:

```
var adrsQuery = (from a in this.Context.Addresses
            where myList.Contains(a.Address_K)
            select new AlternateAddressesDB()
            {
                Line1 = GetAddressLine1(a.AddressLine1),
                Line2 = a.AddressLine2,
                City = a.City,
                State = a.State,
                ZipCode = a.ZipCode
            }).ToList();


        private static string GetAddressLine1(string adrs)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adrs))
                adrs = "Medical Office";

            return adrs;
        }
```

The problem is in `Line1 = GetAddressLine1(a.AddressLine1),`
Looks like I can't call a method in there, How can I do this logic that I have in the method without calling it like that?

Comment: What do you mean "Looks like I can't call a method in there"?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks because it crashes at run-time!!!

Comment: He's using EF or LINQ to SQL - that's the problem. Not LINQ per se.

Comment: @JamesWorld yes, linq to entities

Comment: what type is `this.Context`? Is it `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @Jodrell  it is of DBContext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The others have already explained the problem to you. You can't execute C# methods on the SQL server...

Normally you try to change your query:

```
var adrsQuery = (from a in this.Context.Addresses
        where myList.Contains(a.Address_K)
        select new AlternateAddressesDB()
        {
            Line1 = a.AddressLine1 == null || a.AddressLine1.TrimEnd() == string.Empty ? "Medical Office" : a.AddressLine1,
            Line2 = a.AddressLine2,
            City = a.City,
            State = a.State,
            ZipCode = a.ZipCode
        }).ToList();
```

or you force the execution of your method locally:

```
var adrsQuery = (from a in this.Context.Addresses
        where myList.Contains(a.Address_K)
        select new AlternateAddressesDB()
        {
            Line1 = a.AddressLine1,
            Line2 = a.AddressLine2,
            City = a.City,
            State = a.State,
            ZipCode = a.ZipCode
        })

        .AsEnumerable() // From here the query is executed "locally"

        .Select(a => new AlternateAddressesDB()
        {
            Line1 = GetAddressLine1(a.Line1),
            a.Line2,
            a.City,
            a.State,
            a.ZipCode
        })
        .ToList();
```

You load from the DB the data you need and then locally you create a new set of objects with the data "manipulated"

(this second solution is normally useable only in the final `.Select()`, because if you execute a full `.Where()` locally, you are asking for too many rows to the server, and then you are skipping many of them)

There is a second/third option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29128874/613130
some days ago they asked me how to solve a similar problem. Look at the examples I gave with the solution. The limitation is that you need to be able to convert your method to commands that can be executed by Entity Framework (so you would need to convert the `.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` to something that can be sent to SQL), like:

```
[Expandable]
static string GetAddressLine1(Address address)
{
    // Not necessary to implement, see linked answer
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

static Expression<Func<Address, string>> GetAddressLine1Expression()
{
    return x => x.AddressLine1 == null || x.AddressLine1.TrimEnd() == string.Empty ? "Medical Office" : x.AddressLine1;
}
```

Note that this road is much more complex, and I don't suggest it to the faint of heart, or to those that can follow easier roads (I personally don't use it)

Comment: +1 for different approaches. However, AsEnumerable() before select statement is enough for the situation like @Jodrell does.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't LINQ. You are using an ORM that translates the LINQ you are writing into SQL. It can't translate arbitrary method calls. You'll need to do a transform on the result of the query.

So - get the results *without* trying to call `GetAddressLine1` inline. Then you can use a `Select` to project the results again to fix up your data... eg:

```
var adrsQuery = this.Context.Addresses
.Where(a => myList.Contains(a.Address_K))
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(a => new AlternateAddressesDB
    {
        Line1 = GetAddressLine1(a.AddressLine1),
        Line2 = a.AddressLine2,
        City = a.City,
        State = a.State,
        ZipCode = a.ZipCode
    }).ToList();


private static string GetAddressLine1(string adrs)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adrs))
        adrs = "Medical Office";

    return adrs;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?  How about this ternary operator? Can I do it that way? like this below: Line1 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.AddressLine1) ? "Medical Office" : a.AddressLine1;

Answer (score 2):

I supposed the key to this is `this.Context` which I suppose is some orm. So your linq query is translated to sql and it cannot contain method calls. But your method is simple enough you can inline the logic in your query

```
a.AddressLine1 ?? "value"
```

And yes its not exactly the same but you get the idea.

Comment: well how about this?  Line1 = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.AddressLine1) ? "Medical Office" : a.AddressLine1;

Comment: I cannot say for sure if it will work but it's easy enough to check.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` will not work, but you could of course just do `(a.AddressLine1 == null || a.AddressLine1.Trim() == string.Empty) ? "Medical Office" : a.AddressLine1`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this,

```
var adrsQuery = this.Context.Addresses
    .Where(a => myList.Contains(a.Address_K))
    .ToList() // This line executes the IQueryable and returns an IEnumerable.
    .Select(a => new AlternateAddressesDB
        {
            Line1 = GetAddressLine1(a.AddressLine1),
            Line2 = a.AddressLine2,
            City = a.City,
            State = a.State,
            ZipCode = a.ZipCode
        }).ToList();


    private static string GetAddressLine1(string adrs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(adrs))
            adrs = "Medical Office";

        return adrs;
    }
```

The where clause will be performed server-side which is good, you won't return unnecessary data. The transformation using your non-database functions will be done locally.